# ElasticSearch NEST bulk upsert

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I conducted the following piece of code which performs partial update to the `Content` field in existing documents:

```
var partials = new object[]
            {
                new{
                Id = 1337,
                Content = "test"
            }
            };

            var response = await _elastic.BulkAsync(b => b
                .Index(indexName)
                                         .Index(indexName)
                                         .UpdateMany(partials, (bu, d) => bu.Doc(d))
                                         );
```

However, I want to upsert this document if it does not exist and I'm not sure how. I tried to change `bu.Doc` to `bu.Upsert` however it expects a script.

Answer (score 0):

`Doc()` and `Upsert()` work the same as described in the elastic "Update API" documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html

---

With `Doc()` you specify a partial document to update an existing document. This is not an upsert, only an update

---

With `Upsert()` the documentation states:

> If the document does not already exist, the contents of the upsert element are inserted as a new document. If the document exists, the script is executed

So the `upsert` part specifies what happens if the document does not exist. You need to add a `script` which is executed against the existing document.

---

There is also the `doc_as_upsert` field in conjunction with `doc`. If set to true, then the document in `doc` is inserted if it does not exist, else it is updated. You can set it with `bu.DocAsUpsert()`